# "Unable to cast to Dictionary" error occurred when trying to tween

Tags: roblox

I was trying to make a tween for a text so whenever when player loaded and wait for at least 5 seconds after they loaded in, the text transparency will set to 0 smoothly

Then, I tried to make that happen with a service called TweenService but I was greeted with an error "Unable to cast to Dictionary"

I tried another way by checking the documentation and Forums but didn't find or solve any solutions

Here's my code:

```
local loadingrobloxos = LoadingAssetsGUI.LoadingBootBackground.LoadingRobloxOS
local goallro = loadingrobloxos.TextTransparency == 0
local tweeninfolro = TweenInfo.new(
    0.5,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,
    Enum.EasingDirection.InOut,
    1,
    false
)
local tweenlro = TweenService:Create(loadingrobloxos, tweeninfolro, goallro):Play()
```

What is actually wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [TweenService:Create](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create), you'll see that the last argument of the function is supposed to be a dictionary.

```lua
TweenService:Create(loadingrobloxos, tweeninfolro, goallro)
```

The error is telling you that whatever you passed in for the variable `goallro`, it cannot be converted to a dictionary. And that line is...

```lua
local goallro = loadingrobloxos.TextTransparency == 0
```

This line is not creating a dictionary, it is asking the question, "is loadingrobloxos's TextTransparency currently set to zero?" So the variable `goallro` is set to false. TweenService doesn't know what to do with false, so it throws the error.

Instead, try this :

```lua
local goallro = {
    TextTransparency = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was actually me who didn't see any difference but they are, but now I have to duplicate the same code and change it so it will work fine and smooth.